# How to solve "Error: Fill argument neither colors nor valid variable name(s)" in R?

Tags: r, error, mapping

I have an error in my codes which is: `Error: Fill argument neither colors nor valid variable name(s)`

In the following, I describe how I get this error. Indeed, I have two sets of data and assigned them into two variables named Caifornia_shp and Houses. The information of these two variables are as follow:

```
head(California_shp)
       NAME
1   Alameda
2    Alpine
3    Amador
4     Butte
5 Calaveras
6    Colusa

head(Houses)
  houseValue income houseAge rooms bedrooms population households latitude longitude
1     452600 8.3252       41   880      129        322        126    37.88   -122.23
2     358500 8.3014       21  7099     1106       2401       1138    37.86   -122.22
3     352100 7.2574       52  1467      190        496        177    37.85   -122.24
4     341300 5.6431       52  1274      235        558        219    37.85   -122.25
5     342200 3.8462       52  1627      280        565        259    37.85   -122.25
6     269700 4.0368       52   919      213        413        193    37.85   -122.25
```

I merged Houses and California_shp using the following codes:

```
pts.poly <- point.in.poly(Houses,California_shp)

head(pts.poly@data)

houseValue income houseAge rooms bedrooms population households latitude longitude
1     452600 8.3252       41   880      129        322        126    37.88   -122.23
2     358500 8.3014       21  7099     1106       2401       1138    37.86   -122.22
3     352100 7.2574       52  1467      190        496        177    37.85   -122.24
4     341300 5.6431       52  1274      235        558        219    37.85   -122.25
5     342200 3.8462       52  1627      280        565        259    37.85   -122.25
6     269700 4.0368       52   919      213        413        193    37.85   -122.25
     NAME
1 Alameda
2 Alameda
3 Alameda
4 Alameda
5 Alameda
6 Alameda

head(tapply(pts.poly@data$houseValue,list(pts.poly@data$NAME),mean))
  Alameda    Alpine    Amador     Butte Calaveras    Colusa 
208747.39 118700.00 117146.43  89611.54 107893.75  77731.25
```

When I want to draw a thematic map by codes:

```
tm_shape(California_shp)+tm_borders("Blue",lwd = 2)+tm_fill("houseValue")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Fill argument neither colors nor valid variable name(s)
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Try `tm_shape(pts.poly)`. You are plotting `California_shp` that doesn’t have any variable named `houseValue`, that’s why you get that error.

Comment: I used your suggestion and wrote: `tm_shape(pts.poly)+tm_borders("Blue",lwd = 2)`. Unfortunately, I get the following error: `Error: pts.poly consists of spatial points, so it cannot accept tm_fill/tm_borders/tm_polygons`.

Comment: See also @Spacedman comment https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401855/drawing-thematic-maps-in-r Ideally try to provide the full code you used (reprex) and if possible links to the external files. You can host it on GitHub, Google Drive, etc. so we can check your steps and try to help you

Answer (score 0):

Find a [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/index.html) here. Since you didn't provide the data I used mock data to try to put together a solution.

Note also that the solution is based on the `sf` package, while your objects are on `sp`. You can convert `sp` to `sf` using `st_as_sf()`.

Also, if you are a beginner I would recommend you to stick to `sf` unless you really need to work on `sp`:

```r
library(tigris)
#> To enable 
#> caching of data, set `options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)` in your R script or .Rprofile.
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
library(tmap)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

# Use sf from tigris
California_shp <- counties("California")

Houses <- structure(list(
  houseValue = c(
    452600L, 358500L, 352100L, 341300L,
    342200L, 269700L
  ), income = c(
    8.3252, 8.3014, 7.2574, 5.6431,
    3.8462, 4.0368
  ), houseAge = c(41L, 21L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L),
  rooms = c(880L, 7099L, 1467L, 1274L, 1627L, 919L), bedrooms = c(
    129L,
    1106L, 190L, 235L, 280L, 213L
  ), population = c(
    322L, 2401L,
    496L, 558L, 565L, 413L
  ), households = c(
    126L, 1138L, 177L,
    219L, 259L, 193L
  ), latitude = c(
    37.88, 37.86, 37.85, 37.85,
    37.85, 37.85
  ), longitude = c(
    -122.23, -122.22, -122.24, -122.25,
    -122.25, -122.25
  )
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

# Convert Houses to sf
Houses <- st_as_sf(Houses, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = st_crs(4326))

# Transform both shapes to same CRS
California_shp <- st_transform(California_shp, st_crs(Houses))

# Join points to identify county, transform to dataframe and create mean
pts.poly <- st_join(Houses, California_shp) %>%
  st_drop_geometry() %>%
  group_by(COUNTYFP) %>%
  summarise(houseValue = mean(houseValue))


# Join the newly created dataframe to shape by common variable
California_shp_end <- California_shp %>% left_join(pts.poly, by = "COUNTYFP")

# Plot


tm_shape(California_shp_end) +
  tm_borders("Blue", lwd = 2) +
  tm_fill("houseValue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @dieghernan. I still receive errors. I need to use `point_in_poly` function, `mean` function, and `tapply`.

Comment: Your `pts.poly` is a `SpatialPointDataFrame`.  `tapply/mean` gives you a vector with the mean of `houseValue` by `NAME`.  If you really need to go that way, try to paste the result of your `tapply` back to `California_shp`. As you are mapping from `California_shp` you have to figure out the way to paste your values to that shape. All that is already solved in my reprex however I understand that for some reason you need to focus more on the process rather than in the result

Comment: Thank you @dieghernan. How can I paste the result of my `tapply` to `California-shp`?

Comment: Figure out the way of producing a dataframe from tapply and use merge https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/versions/1.4-5/topics/merge